# Laravel 5 Eloquent events update

Tags: events, eloquent, laravel-5, webhooks

I have Eloquent Model `User` which has property `$amount`. How can I write `Handler` for updating user's `amount` `Event` (when he charges his balance) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = User::first(); // User object

$user->amount = 5;

$user->save();
```

Did you read the documentation?

For a better understanding of basic functionality I suggest you start with reading the documentation. Here you can find a very thorough explanation of [Eloquent - Basic Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#basic-updates)

Answer (score 0):

You could select the user you want then update it :

```
$user = User::find(id)->update(['amount'=>5]);
```

Hope this helps.